# Why are there a lot of blobs for only 4 tags in private docker registry?

Tags: docker-registry

I have a private docker registry and garbage-collection doesn't clear any space. My image has only 4 tags but running `garbage-collection --dry-run` finds a bunch of manifests and blobs.
Tag output:

```
1   "0.0.18"
4   "0.0.16"
5   "0.0.19-SNAPSHOT"
6   "0.0.17"
```

Garbage collection output:

```
first-image
first-image: marking manifest sha256:0097c9845b15c656fce4641342e2b326e876552e3ef62d2d00c60c3e60cdc1a5 
first-image: marking blob sha256:a3d9a3da71d2604e1ea5b79aaeaaf11b3fc8bbd433cbb145df13342f4691fc88
first-image: marking blob sha256:9d19ee268e0d7bcf6716e6658ee1b0384a71d6f2f9aa1ae2085610cf7c7b316f
first-image: marking blob sha256:aa5b63dfa01646dce4380e03beced61802400b00a00eb6c41a45612e6fb57e96
first-image: marking manifest sha256:00d35e06b03f5c1858f0f961de3d5f8a47af57b16c0a3d122ba3b8bd9da69b06 
first-image: marking blob sha256:fbcf20091271855e22afcb35257403b112695870570278e151e5ece7f7c5fbef
first-image: marking blob sha256:9d19ee268e0d7bcf6716e6658ee1b0384a71d6f2f9aa1ae2085610cf7c7b316f
first-image: marking blob sha256:a25c902218f996c9c79ecf60c1687d9aba1fd6f0d239f4f195608e32b37c1451
first-image: marking manifest sha256:018ee5663046259e60e944aab1f5cb71691a4a5107d2173ee1d9f9c9ac18b86c 
first-image: marking blob sha256:a838860453789b1dcc933ad94e68cafed60abbb1ca321f73ed247160f4e06b89
first-image: marking blob sha256:8789581436c067f1467941de4a460158912c663650f915502c8009d595296b61
first-image: marking blob sha256:449540e442f7d79059742f178ec0c330e00a7c42559cb4549d9b191f1ca28114
first-image: marking manifest sha256:02691ae1100a76e28290ea3baea3665bdb0f8a1b1403a866f695927a105c0061 
first-image: marking blob sha256:50d4a96b5c596bda8d4b576897c5b923f3c7630ef212e6fd893f770c425e9c4a
first-image: marking blob sha256:74ac377868f863e123f24c409f79709f7563fa464557c36a09cf6f85c8b92b7f
first-image: marking blob sha256:a182a611d05b01879f065473c49fb968b8d30312f931350ea07af1c46aa8b4f9
first-image: marking manifest sha256:02a459655d04652cbd8e5a835c7454ebf1c1021008ce0cca759e41a322ea212c 
first-image: marking blob sha256:5c80b83719b8f1fa746a084a3adf4eb89d989aac781db8e0472423b9988a809d
first-image: marking blob sha256:6e3729cf69e0ce2de9e779575a1fec8b7fb5efdfa822829290ab6d5d1bc3e797
first-image: marking blob sha256:4d8d923227d8dc300e1ddab1b65c83c0eff7f4a7105d958420872f7138b79735
first-image: marking manifest sha256:031403af9527033e9e01e732c15fa103a04528220b7be2cfa283d634f1905a34 
first-image: marking blob sha256:e37b7ebb7514f8fc8e31a4646652b40c0879d0bc37dcfc946655f3785b64b466
first-image: marking blob sha256:1bc677758ad7fa4503417ae5be18809c5a8679b5b36fcd1464d5a8e41cb13305
first-image: marking blob sha256:0d0e0ecb256ae3e8b7625494ed35189f845766552b7159a17f634706e28a9687
.
.
.
.

30151 blobs marked, 0 blobs and 0 manifests eligible for deletion
```

The list is omitted, it has around 70 manifest entries. Old SNAPSHOT tags were deleted but it seems that manifests remained.

I have a second image where all the tags are deleted, but garbage-collect also finds manifests and blobs, none of which are eligible for deletion.

Why are there so many manifests for only 4 tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `garbage-collection` command in the distribution project cleans up blobs that have no manifests referencing them. A manifest can exist without a tag, so if the same tags have been replaced multiple times, there may be a lot of old manifests.

As for how many blobs should exist with only 4 tags, we can't say without more details. Each tag may point to an OCI Index / Docker manifest list, which then points to an array of manifests, each of which contain a list of layer blobs plus their config blob. Depending on how many platforms and how many layers, you will have a different blob count.

You can instruct `garbage-collect` to delete untagged manifests, but that comes with a big warning. [That deletion includes every untagged child manifest of a multi-platform manifest](https://github.com/distribution/distribution/issues/3178). The result of doing that cleanup is the top level tag still resolved, but all of the platform specific image contents were deleted out from under it.

For only 4 tags, I'd take a backup, or pull the images to local disk with a tool like crane, skopeo, or regctl. Then you can try the potentiall destructive `garbage-collect --delete-untagged`.

Comment: We replace the same tag multiple times while developing so that's probably the reason. There is one image without tags that still has manifests and blobs and this image is unneeded. Would it be safe do delete these manifests and expect  garbage-collect to cleanup the rest? Or is there a better way to delete unwanted images?

Comment: For only 4 tags, I'd take a backup, or pull the images to local disk with a tool like crane, skopeo, or regctl and then clean the registry.